# On which Stack Exchange site should a Google query question be asked

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I asked on Stack Overflow a question about "How do I find on the Internet hits for a word with a dash in the middle?". [The question got delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8275631/65889). I assume because it was regarded as off-topic. On which Stack Exchange site should a Google query question like "How do I find on the Internet hits for a word with a dash in the middle?" get asked? (this question is despite its easy appearance *not* trivial.)

Comment: I'm removing the second part of the question because it is covered in the faq: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean

Comment: You can't see deleted questions until you have 10K reputation - but you're right, it was closed as Off Topic then got deleted.

Comment: Found the question on _google cache_! Seems to be the only way for me to see my own question again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think your question would be on-topic on [Web Applications.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). From their FAQ:

> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, **Google**, or any other website which behaves like an application

It might even be a duplicate of [How can I search for a keyword with special characters in Google Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23/how-can-i-search-for-a-keyword-with-special-characters-in-google-search)

Comment: Thanks for this. Have asked the question there (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21518/how-do-i-find-on-the-internet-hits-for-a-word-with-a-dash-in-the-middle), because I don't think it is a duplicate of the above mentioned older question.